# LED voltage drop in open circuit

Tags: led

Sorry for the noob question, but I really can't figure this out. I am playing with an oscilloscope, and starting at the very basics.

I have a resistor connected to the 5V positive power rail. This, in turn, is connected to a red LED. The ground is not connected. When I measure the voltage between the resister and the LED, it is 5V, as expected. When I measure the voltage on the other side of the LED, it is 3.6V. The LED is not lit, as expected, because the ground is not connected to it.

My question is, why is that value 3.6V, and not 5V?

When I connect the ground to the LED, The voltage between the resistor and the LED is 2.6V.

Again sorry for the silly question, but I really don't understand why this is occurring.

Comment: Show the exact schematic of how things are connected and where the measurements are taking place. Including the GND connection of the scope probe.

Comment: The oscilliscope input has a resistance of 1 MOhm or 10 MOhm - this will apparently draw enough current to create a voltage drop of 1.4 volts across the LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your measurements indicate

- Vf=1.4V at <1uA  (10Meg probe current 3.6V/10M= 0.36uA)
- Vf=2.4V at some unknown current probably > than rated 20mA with unknown R to 5V
- measure the current by V drop / R value = I

> I will guess  you used  old Gallium Arsenide (GaAs) LED at 660nmD or
>   used too small an R value or got a poor quality LED with high ESR.

All diodes behave this way, except depending on chemistry, will have different thresholds. The chemistry affects non-LEDs like Ge, Schottky and Silicon as well as LEDs where the Vth or threshold voltage increases with higher activation energy and shorter wavelength colours.

Although datasheets only describe the Vf or forward voltage at some rated If, this is always about 10% higher than the Threshold voltage at some tiny current.
We have a dynamic impedance that reduces  as I increases around this threshold Vth and then the junction "saturates" and the internal series resistance or ESR effectively dominates the V/I slope to a constant value.

there is also a linear realation ship between ESR and the PD or package dissipation rated value, that I have discovered is between 0.5 and 1 Ω per watt. ESR =1/Pd (+/-50% )

This applies to all diode junctions for any type and power rating. As manufacturing design and process controls have improved over the decades this has reduced from ESR values in the 70's using GaAs where ESR was around 2~3 Ω/W.  Current state of the Art power LED are going under 0.5Ω/W in ESR and may continue slightly in future decades.

### What does this mean?

- You can estimate the change in voltage drop using rated current from any given Vf. ( with a certain tolerance depending on where the parts came from)
- You can estimate the Vf for Blue/White using Vf=2.8+ If*1/Pd for the package power rating at Tj=80'C
- You can expect Vbe on a transistor to be 0.52V with a 1uA base current or 0.65V at nominal midrange current
- you can understand why we often say 0.6~0.7V for Vbe even though it can be lower or higher with different current levels.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

In the forward direction the led needs to overcome the junction barrier. In your case this is missing 1.4 V. You find the same behaviour when trying to diagnose a faulty string with leds in series. This even with high impediance measureing equipment